# View.performClick not triggered

Tags: android

I have the following code in an adapter to handle clicks on a CheckBox. `gview` references the View argument in the adapter's `getView()`

Adapter code:

```
        selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                if (selection.size() == 0)
                    gview.performLongClick();
                else
                    gview.performClick();
            else
                if (selection.size() == 1)
                    gview.performLongClick();
                else
                    gview.performClick();
        }

    });
```

The logic is in the activity containing the `ListView` where `performLongClick()` triggers `OnItemLongClick` and `performClick()` **should** trigger `onItemClick()` **but my problem is that it doesn't**:

Activity code:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long itemId) {
    if (listMode == MODE_NAVIGATION){
        home.browserFragment.loadUrl(bookmarks.findById((int)itemId).getUrl());
        home.browserFragment.closeBookmarks();
    } else{
        updateMultipleItemsSelection((int)itemId);

    }
}

  @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long itemId) {
    if (listMode == MODE_SELECTION){
        deactivateSelectionMode();
    }else{
        activateSelectionMode();
        updateMultipleItemsSelection((int)itemId);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone see a possible solution to that problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is gview referencing in this case?

Comment: @DeeV: the View argument in getView()

Comment: The only thing I can think of is gView isn't referencing what you think it's referencing. You say it's the convertView argument in getView(), but if you're not reusing that view and you're returning a new one, then the listener won't be attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the checkbox is focusable, the surrounding listview item isn't.  Try setting the listview item as focusable in XML.  If that doesn't work, you can try setting the checkbox to *not* focusable (it'll still be checkable).

Comment: Thanks. But the checkbox is already not focusable, and setting the list view item as focusable prevents both long and normal clicks on the listview item to be performed. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        pi = (PackageInfo) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        cb.performClick();
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue.add(tv.getText().toString());
        } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue.remove(tv.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```